# Are questions about interaction with people on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I ask myself if questions which are mostly about interaction with other humans while doing outdoor activities on-topic?

An example question:

*How to react to a person which leave litter behind on the trail?*

Edit:

I'm thinking about that cause other communities had this problem, too. Check out academia for example:

- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56245/how-should-i-react-to-seeing-another-student-cheat-on-an-exam
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/53853/how-should-i-let-a-professor-know-that-i-dont-want-to-work-for-her/53887#53887
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/useful-strategies-for-answering-dumb-questions-in-a-talk/17076#17076

Answer (score 1):

That specific one wouldn't be on topic, because:

- it is about interpersonal relationships, not outdoors
- it is entirely opinion-based - what works for you may not work for me

If you have questions that are specific to being Outdoors, and that have a definable answer, then they should be on topic.

Comment: Don't think that it's that easy: http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+should+i+react

Comment: Academia and Workplace are a little different in this respect, as a large proportion of their scope is specifically interpersonal relationships. Additionally, a University or an office are both fairly well regulated formal environments, whereas Outdoors really isn't.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, I think this answer would have domain-specific information like "tell a ranger" or "report to this or that organization" etc. Similar question: how should I react to poachers in national park? That said, unless it's an emergency, most of these 'how to I react to law breaker' answers are going to be "tell a park ranger and let them deal with it"...

Comment: I gave it a try: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10196/how-to-react-to-someone-measuring-distances